# Infix -> postfix translator in antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I need to define the semantic actions required to translate infix notation to postfix notation by embedding semantic actions as Java code in the g4 grammar file.

For example, when I try to input "a + b * c", I want it to print out a b c * +. But mine is: a b + c *

It happens only when there are * and /

This is my grammar file

```
grammar Simple;
// productions for syntax analysis
start returns [String node]: e=expr  <EOF>              {$node = $e.node;};

expr returns [String node]: t=term r=rest               {$node = $t.node + " " + $r.node;};

rest returns [String node]: '*' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + " " + $r.node + "*" ;}
                          | '/' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + " " + $r.node + "/" ;}
                          | '+' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + "+"  + $r.node ;}
                          | '-' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + "-" + $r.node   ;}
                          |                              {$node = " ";};

term returns [String node]: '(' e=expr ')'              {$node = $e.node;}
                           |Id                          {$node = $Id.text;}
                           | Num                        {$node = $Num.text;};


// productions for lexical analysis
Id  : [a-z]+ ;
Num : [0-9]+ ;
WS  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n'|) -> skip;
```

This is my main file

```
import java.io.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class SimpleMain {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        CharStream charStream =  CharStreams.fromFileName("src/test.expression");
        SimpleLexer lexer = new SimpleLexer(charStream);
        SimpleParser parser = new SimpleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        String postfix = parser.start().node; /* Run translator */
        System.out.println(postfix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're attempting to accomplish with the `(op) t=term r=rest` style of rules.  They won't match the infix operator syntax you have specified for your input.  (It looks a bit like it might be a mis-translation from a non-antler grammar, but I'd just be guessing)

First, a couple of things to watch out for:

- empty rule alternatives:

```
rest returns [String node]: '*' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + " " + $r.node + "*" ;}
                          | '/' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + " " + $r.node + "/" ;}
                          | '+' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + "+"  + $r.node ;}
                          | '-' t=term r=rest           {$node = $t.node + "-" + $r.node   ;}
                          |                              {$node = " ";};  //
```

The last alternative is empty and will match "nothing". This can be used to indicate that the contents of a rule may be optional, but you don't want that here.

```
WS  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n'|) -> skip;
```

The `|)` creates an empty alternative and ANTLR warns you that this is not a good idea in a Lexer rule.  `WS:  [ \t\r\n] -> skip;` makes this simpler.

- You also need to understand that ANTLR uses the order of alternatives to establish precedence in expressions and, that it's best to have the "terminal" expression nodes in the `expr` rule itself, as they are, indeed `expr`s.
  Because alternatives establish precedence, you'll want '*' and '/' in the same alternative as they have the same precedence (same for '+' and '-')

With those things in mind, This seems to give the correct output:

```
grammar Simple
    ;
// productions for syntax analysis
start
    returns[String node]: e = expr <EOF> {$node = $e.node;};

expr
    returns[String node]
    : lhs = expr op = ('*' | '/') rhs = expr 
        {$node = $lhs.node + " " + $rhs.node + " " + $op.text ; }
    | lhs = expr op = ('+' | '-') rhs = expr 
        {$node = $lhs.node + " "  + $rhs.node + " " + $op.text ; }
    | '(' e = expr ')' {$node = $e.node;}
    | Id {$node = $Id.text;}
    | Num {$node = $Num.text;}
    ;

term
    returns[String node]
    : '(' e = expr ')' {$node = $e.node;}
    | Id {$node = $Id.text;}
    | Num {$node = $Num.text;}
    ;

// productions for lexical analysis 
Id:  [a-z]+;
Num: [0-9]+;
WS:  [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

output for `a + b * c` is `a b c * +`

And output for `a + b * c / d` is `a b c * d / +`

Comment: Oh! Now I am clearly understood. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to know.  BTW, it's good practice in StackOverflow, to "accept" an answer that answers your question.  That's not just for reputation of those answering questions; it also marks a question as "Answered" so those of us watching for "unanswered" questions don't continue to see it in the list even though it has been answered.